# Wiring garage heater

Tags: electrical

I want to install a garage heater in my garage. It will be mounted near the electrical panel. Problem is I cant add any more breakers to the panel and the heater has to be hard wired. It is a 5000 watt heater. How can I wire it and what amp breaker do I need to use? The panel already has 30,40, and 60 amp breakers.

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel in question please, including any labeling on the inside of the door?

Comment: We need a photo of the panel tag to see if tandems are allowed. We are hoping the panel model number will have a number like 20-26 or 20-40 the first number is the full sized breakers allowed the second is the number of circuits so if 20-26 will allow 6 positions to use tandems , double stuff or cheater breakers. It could be a much larger number 40-60 just another of many possibilities.